# access component `this` from container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using props to pass in functions that my component needs to run. Keeping the component as dumb as possible. Instead of putting into the functions into the react class.

I need to update my component state, but I'm having trouble accessing setState from within my prop function. I've tried doing something like, so my function can access it, but I keep getting an error:

Component

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadImage(this.props.src).bind(this);
  }
```

Container Load Image Function

```
let loadImage = (src)=>{
  console.log('loading Image');    
  fetch(src).then(function( data ) {
      console.log('success');
      that.setState({'imgUrl':src});
  }).catch(function( error ) {
      console.log('fail');
      setTimeout(loadImage(src), 1000);
  });

};
```

Error:

```
component.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined(…)
```

1. Why is bind undefined on this prop function?
2. Am I just approaching this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing `loadImage` and what it returns. Mind sharing that?

Comment: @ZekeDroid Didn't think it had much bearing, but just added it.

Comment: It does because right now you're binding the return value of that prop. Meaning that if that prop has no return statement, which looks like the case, then you're trying to bind to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `loadImage` doesn't return a function then you are probably calling `bind` on undefined. You might want to do `this.props.loadImage.bind(this, this.props.src);` instead.

Comment: can also bind and call separately to explicitly set params:

`this.props.loadImage.bind(this).call(undefined, this.props.src)`

Comment: I believe `bind` will only return a function, right? which means `loadImage` won't be `call`ed

Comment: Ahhh for some reason I thought bind called the function as well, still new to using bind. Using bind with call worked great thought. Good to know there. Thanks @guavacat and @@mr-meeseeks

Answer (score 1):

Why bind `this` in the first place?

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: ''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.doSomething('hello');
  }
  doSomething(data) {
    this.setState({
      data
    }, () => console.log(this.state));
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.data}</div> 
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: At least from what I understand, it's best practice to keep the components as simple as possible, focused on display. Putting functions in a container file to handle functionality and data retrieval. This practice seams to add some extra boilerplate code at times, but I find it worth it overall.